# Why don't Jews proselytize? Is it a law or a custom?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism

Is there a specific law that forbids Jews from proselytizing or was it just a custom that became the norm because unlike other major religions Jews believe that members of other faiths can fulfill God's will & also unlike other major religions the Jewish people never governed large populations of non Jews?

Comment: relevant: [Was Judaism ever a proselytizing religion?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17635/was-judaism-ever-a-proselytizing-religion/7539)

Comment: "Jews believe that members of other faiths can fulfill God's will". Not exactly. A non-Jewish person must believe and do certain things as laid out in the [Seven Laws of Noah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Laws_of_Noah). The idea is just that a person doesn't have to be _Jewish_ in order to be right in God's eyes.

Comment: I would also say that it is so difficult to actually be a Jew that many Jews do their best to run away from Judaism. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/111429/why-are-there-such-few-observant-jews/111433#111433